# Get a stream of tweets with hashtags from twitter

Tags: api, twitter, stream

Search in Twitter supports 'filter:hashtags' option that show stream of tweets that contains 
hashtags.
https://twitter.com/search?q=filter%3Ahashtags&src=typd&f=realtime

Is there a way to get such stream via API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes using the search function though the API you can retrieve tweets with a Hashtag.  Example: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi`

[Using the Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

Comment: That's not the stream API.

Comment: @roj1512 this question is from 2014.  You think things may have changed?   This was the api endpoint then.

Comment: There should have been a streaming API back in 2014, too, according to the link provided in the question (`f=realtime`).

Comment: sorry I dont have a time machine to go back and check to then.  You may want to try and check newer questions. For what is available now.